# Inner join queries return similar sets of data

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to get data out of a two tables by an inner join. I can select the data and use a foreach loop to print it out but I get multiple sets of the same data.

This is my SQL statement

```
SELECT workout.*, exercise.ExerciseName, exercise.Sets, exercise.Reps, exercise.Weight
FROM workout
INNER JOIN exercise
ON workout.WorkoutID = exercise.WORKOUTID
WHERE workout.WorkoutID = 1
```

It brings back WorkoutID, UserID, WorkoutName, & Description three times despite it being the same information. I assume this is because ExerciseName, Sets, Reps, & Weight are different for each. This is problematic when I loop through the data to echo it out as it prints out the data 3 times, once for each different exercise.

How do I get WorkoutID, UserID, WorkoutName, & Description once and continue to get the different ExerciseName, Sets, Reps, & Weights. If that is even possible.

Thanks.

Comment: Well if the row contains the same data and you want to show fields that can't be aggregated, there's not much to do unless I'm not getting your question right.

Comment: So to echo out the data when it is returned would I have to go into the array just grab the workout name and description then loop through all of the other data?

Comment: Yes. You would have to loop for each workout id the detail of each workout.

Answer (score 0):

How do you want to see `WorkoutID, UserID, WorkoutName, & Description` only one time if your user is linked to 3 exercices with 3 different weight (correct me if i misread the question)

if the weights are the same and you want to see the information once, you can add the following command :
select `DISTINCT` [...]

Comment: I've since dropped the weight table so we can ignore that. What I want to show is: Bench Press 3 sets of 10 reps. Squats 5 sets of 5 reps. Which would all be connected to Workout 1 for example.

Comment: Please give us the list of fields and values, it will be more easy to understand your needs :) does this query work? `select exercise.ExerciseName, exercise.Sets, exercise.Reps from exercise WHERE WorkoutID = 1`

Answer (score 0):

To sum my comments as an answer:

When you have multiple rows that contain information about a single entity like the detail of a workout in this case, there is no grouping possible to remove the repetition of the workout id and user id which will always be the same. What you want to do is iterate on the result for each id.